# how to make update into table on self join using laravel elquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

i have (news ) table , it has (id as primary key) and (parent_id) as master in the same table

the process for insert news :

1) insert (news category ) which represent the parent for the news it's self.
2) insert ( the news it's self) with the chosen parent_id .

i can't figure out the (self join ) syntax to do the following with eloquent to delete the (parent_id and it's children) :

here is the syntax in mysql :

```
UPDATE news n1 , news n2 

SET n1.deleted_at = '2016-05-20 16:30:05' ,

  n2.deleted_at = '2016-05-20 16:30:05'

  WHERE n1.id = n2.parent_id
```

any idea about how to do that using laravel eloquent ??

Comment: Why not just two different queries?

Comment: sounds logically ,,, but one query sounds too logical for me , can you help with the syntax for one query  @sagi ?

Comment: Won't it work if you set up a foreign key in the table and have `ON DELETE CASCADE`. Then when you delete a parent all the children will be deleted too from this relationship.